# How do I get the current remaining length of a string?

Tags: pl-i

I've got an array

```
DO WHILE (NOTEND = '1'B);
    IF (LENGTH(VALUELIST) > 8) THEN DO;
        VALUELIST = SUBSTR(VALUELIST,8);
    END;
    ELSE DO;
        NOTEND='0'B;
    END;
END;
```

Now my problem is: Length(valuelist) always returns the original definition of the characterfield: CHAR(500) thus 500. I didn't find any other command there though.

Thus my question is: How can I get the remaining length of that string (aka of its content not the char array itself)?

Comment: Something like `LENGTH(TRIM(VALUELIST))` perhaps?

Comment: does that mena if I use substr this way it fills it up to the 500 char with blanks? @LasseV.Karlsen ? (that.....is unexpetected then trying it out)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen that was it tnx

Comment: `CHAR` does that if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided by Lasse V. Karlsen is one method. A different, possibly more straight-forward solution would be to use `CHAR VARYING` (a.k.a. `VARCHAR`), which maintains the length of the string. After the assignment, `LENGTH(VALUELIST)` will be correct (8 less than the previous length).